# Linq-to-sql left join one to many

Tags: linq-to-sql

Here is my `Linq-to-sql` query:

```
var ds = (from f in dc.Fields
          from l in dc.Units.Where( ltu => ltu.TestID == f.Testid && ltu.tid == tid && ltu.Lbid != null).DefaultIfEmpty()
          from s in dc.Sites.Where( st => st.lbid == l.Lbid).DefaultIfEmpty()
          where f.tid == tid && f.tablename == e.Parameters[0].Value && f.tablename.Contains(tableprefix) 
          orderby f.fieldorder
          select new { ID = f.id, Units = "Units: " + l.Unit + "For Sites: " + s.siteid}
```

How I can change code so if a field has more than one Unit and Site then select all of them and not just the first.

```
**Fields**
ID    |    Testid    |   fieldorder  |  tablename  |  tid
 0    |     test1    |      1        |    tbl1     |   100
 1    |     test2    |      2        |    tbl2     |   100

**Units**
ID    |    TestID   |  tid   |   Lbid   |  Unit
 0    |     test1   |  100   |   Lb1    |   m/s
 1    |     test1   |  100   |   Lb1    |   km/s

**Sites**
ID    |    siteid   |  lbid
 0    |     100     |   Lb1
 1    |     200     |   Lb1
```

So what I want to get is :

> ID = 0 , Units = "Units: " m/s , km/s "For Sites: " 100, 200

Comment: You need to show your class model. I don't think your "join" is correct (`ltu.TestID == f.Testid`), but that's hard to judge. Why don't you use navigation properties?

Comment: Why are you mixing query comprehension and lambda syntax?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure your query is returning the result you expect (I am getting four rows back from it), but here is the modification to combine the rows by Fields.ID:

```
var ds = from f in dc.Fields
         from l in dc.Units.Where(ltu => ltu.TestID == f.Testid && ltu.tid == tid && ltu.Lbid != null).DefaultIfEmpty()
         from s in dc.Sites.Where(st => st.lbid == l?.Lbid).DefaultIfEmpty()
         where f.tid == tid && f.tablename == e.Parameters[0].Value && f.tablename.Contains(tableprefix)
         group new { f, l, s } by f.ID into flsg
         orderby flsg.First().f.fieldorder
         select new { ID = flsg.Key, Units = "Units: " + String.Join(",", flsg.Select(fls => fls.l?.Unit)) + " For Sites: " + String.Join(",", flsg.Select(fls => fls.s?.siteid)) };
```

Comment: I cant use the `?` in the expressions like `Where(st => st.lbid == l?.Lbid)` I get errors. And if I don't use the `?` I receive this error: `Could not translate expression …into SQL and could not treat it as a local expression.` for this part: `String.Join(",", flsg.Select(fls => fls.s.siteid))`

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't pay (enough) attention to your LINQ to SQL mention. Let me work on it.